# One proof of linear momentum of the system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

[image]

[image]

[image]

I copy and paste all the proof here, but I'm confused about the last step, which is that the summation of the internal force and be written as two other summations.

Comment: Hi, This is not homework question, ok? It's the proof provided by the Marion book.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to say the same thing as the author but explain more with words. I am also going to take the external force to be zero and ignore it, since the part you're confused about isn't independent of the external force.

The force on particle $\alpha$, due to all the other particles in the system is

$$f_{\alpha} = \sum_{\textrm{all other particles }\beta}\textrm{force on }\alpha \textrm{ due to }\beta \equiv \sum_{\beta}f_{\alpha \beta}.\quad(1)$$

In other words, the total force on $\alpha$ is the sum of all the forces on $\alpha$ coming from each other particle in the system, which we've indexed with the symbol $\beta$.

Now let's ask, what is the total momentum change of the system? The time rate of change of momentum of particle $\alpha$ is

$$\dot{p}_{\alpha} = f_{\alpha} \qquad \textrm{(Newton's second law)}.\quad(2)$$

Therefore, substituting (1) into (2) we can write the time rate of change of $\alpha$'s momentum as

$$\dot{p}_{\alpha} = f_{\alpha} = \sum_{\beta}f_{\alpha \beta}.\quad(3)$$

Now, the *total* momentum of *all* the particles in the system is just the sum of the momenta of the individual particles,

$$p_{\textrm{total}} = \sum_{\alpha}p_{\alpha},\quad(4)$$

so the time rate of change of the total momentum is

$$\dot{p}_{\textrm{total}} = \sum_{\alpha}\dot{p}_{\alpha}.\quad(5)$$

If we substitute (3) into (5) we get

$$\dot{p}_{\textrm{total}} = \sum_{\alpha}\sum_{\beta}f_{\alpha \beta}.\quad(6)$$

This double sum is what confused you (I think). What this sum does is go over every pair of particles, labeled by $\alpha$ and $\beta$. For each pair of particles it sums the force exerted by the $\beta^{\textrm{th}}$ particle on the $\alpha^{\textrm{th}}$ particle. Now, you know from Newton's third law that the force of $\alpha$ on $\beta$ is exactly minus the force of $\beta$ on $\alpha$. In that sum, for every term $f_{\alpha\beta}$ there's exactly one opposite term $f_{\beta \alpha}$, so when you sum them all up, they cancel in pairs. That means that the sum must be zero, and in the end we get

$$\dot{p}_{\textrm{total}} = 0,\quad(7)$$

which says that, in the absence of external force, the momentum is constant.

Now let's do that last part purely mathematically. The sum in (6) goes over all pairs of particles, including terms like $f_{\alpha \alpha}$ which is the force a particle exerts on itself.  A particle doesn't actually exert force on itself, ie. $f_{\alpha \alpha}=0$ for all $\alpha$, so we can remove those terms without changing the value of the sum. This leaves us with

$$\dot{p}_{\textrm{total}} = \sum_{\alpha \beta,\,\,\alpha \neq \beta} f_{\alpha \beta},\quad(8)$$

which literally means "sum over all pairs of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ except the ones where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the same particle."

[image: Diagram of the sum in (8)]

In the attached diagram you can see an illustration of this sum. The boxes are terms in the sum, and the ones with x's in them are the ones we throw out because they're zero. You can now see that every box below the diagonal line of x'ed boxes has a counterpart above the diagonal. For example, the box at $\alpha=3$ and $\beta=2$ has a counterpart at $\alpha=2$ and $\beta=3$. I've colored those boxes green to help see what I mean. Let's write the part of the sum that counts only the boxes above the diagonal. To be above the diagonal, you need to have $\alpha<\beta$. Therefore, the sum over the boxes above the diagonal is

$$\dot{p}_{\textrm{total}} = \sum_{\alpha < \beta}f_{\alpha \beta}.\quad(9)$$

Now to add in the boxes below the diagonal, we just add the partner of each box above, like this

$$\dot{p}_{\textrm{total}} = \sum_{\alpha < \beta}f_{\alpha \beta} + f_{\beta \alpha}.\quad(10)$$

Newton's third law is that the force on $\alpha$ due to $\beta$ is exactly the negative of the force on $\beta$ due to $\alpha$. In math, that's written

$$f_{\alpha \beta} = -f_{\beta \alpha}\quad(11)$$

Inserting (11) into (10) gives you

$$\dot{p}_{\textrm{total}} = \sum_{\alpha < \beta}f_{\alpha \beta} - f_{\alpha \beta} = 0$$

just as we said before.